# How to use list in list with Flask-Jinja Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, flask, jinja2

I try to make few tables with data import on web page! I'm using Flask-Jinja with Python. 
For example I have this double list:

```
list = [[{'pricebb': 1199.99, 'model': 'model1', 'pricebh': 1199, 'pricea': 1299},  {'pricebb': 1199.99, 'model': 'model2', 'pricebh': 1199, 'pricea': 1299}, {'pricebb': 1499.99, 'model': 'model3', 'pricebh': 1499, 'pricea': 1599}], [{'pricebb': 399.99, 'model': 'model4', 'pricebh': 459, 'pricea': 499}, {'pricebb': 599.99, 'model': 'model5', 'pricebh': 669, 'pricea': 699}, {'pricebb': None, 'model': 'model6', 'pricebh': 899, 'pricea': 999}]]
```

I want to separate it with loop and create 2 different tables on one page. 
If I use Python with list[0] I get 1-st sublist, but when I try it on Flask:

```
{% for post in posts %}
   <p>{{post[0]}}</p>
       {% endfor %}
```

It return to me - model1 and model4) Why its happened? How can I get 1-st sublist from list? Have you any idea !? Thank you!

```
run1()

list= sqlselect()# here is array from DB
a = list # its a list sample that I posted above



@FlaskApp2.route('/', methods=('Get', 'Post'))
@FlaskApp2.route('/index')
def index():
    user = {'nickname': 'parser'}  # fake user
    return render_template("index.html",
                           title='Web',
                           user=user,
                           posts=list, describe=des)
```

Here is index.html:

```
<table>
    <caption>products compare list ({{item}})</caption>


    <thead>
    <tr>

    <th>qqq.com</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>qqq.com</th>
    <th>qqq.com</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    {% for post in posts %}
    <p>{{post[0]}}</p>
       {% endfor %}

</table>
```

Comment: Can you share the whole program

Comment: Updated........

Answer (score 5):

You can access internal lists by `posts[0]` - first list, and `posts[1]` -
 second list (you never should name a variable with a reserved word in python - don't name your var `list`, but `mylist`). So to access the elements for the first list you should use:

```
{% for post in posts[0] %}
    {% for key, value in post.items %}
    <p>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

and for the second list:

```
{% for post in posts[1] %}
    {% for key, value in post.items %}
    <p>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @TheRutubeify glad it worked, now you can mark the answer as accepted to close the question.